# how to split column name declarations in sql create statement?

Tags: php, sql, regex

I have trimmed create statement only to the column declarations:

```
`user,id` PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, [col,1] NOT NULL, "another,col" UNIQUE,
'`and`,''another'',"one"' INTEGER, and_so_on
```

The caveat is that commas are not only between columns declarations but may be in the column names. (Yes, I know that it is bad habit to place them into column names.)

effect should be like this:

```
array (
 `user,id` PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 [col,1] NOT NULL,
 "another,col" UNIQUE,
 '`and`,''another'',"one"' INTEGER,
 and_so_on
)
```

Comment: Wow, that is terrible. Why the hell do you need commas in column names?

Comment: I don't need but I may deal with it, that is somebody put it in there and I need my function to don't get stupid when encountering this. Being bad habit the code above is completely valid mysql syntax.

Comment: Will you always have column names in backticks? If yes `preg_split` should work for you with relatively easy regex

Comment: Unfortunately no, of course you need some kind of encapsulation for column name if you are going to use comma in it but there could be used mixture of all allowed quoting styles for columns even in the same table.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to split names into components, why not use an underscore?  `user_id`, `col_1`, `another_col`, `and_another_one`.

Comment: He obviously is not looking for that. He's got wicked column names and needs to work around that.

Comment: If I was the one who created the table that would be ok.

Comment: That's all well and good, but adding a bit of clarification to the question would make it less ambiguous.